# Setting up PostgreSQL driver on Azure Databricks

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift, databricks, azure-databricks

How can I modify the code below to install a PostgreSQL JDBC driver instead of MS SQL? My goal is to use pyodbc to connect to a Redshift database from Azure Databricks. I thought that the PostgreSQL JDBC driver was already installed in my Databricks runtime by default, but when I run `pyodbc.drivers()` I get just "['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']" so I guess not. And what would the pyodbc.connect() string look like once the PostgreSQL driver is installed? If it's easier, we can instead use Amazon's recommended JDBC driver for Redshift.

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your approach and use [correct instructions to install and configure the Redshift driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-odbc-connection.html#install-odbc-driver-linux):

1. install `unixodbc-dev` via `apt-get`
2. download the 64-bit Debian package (actual link is in the documentation)
3. modify `odbcinst.ini` with following information (you can store that file on DBFS and copy from it, or copy `/opt/amazon/redshiftodbc/lib/64/amazon.redshiftodbc.ini` into `odbcinst.ini`):

```
[ODBC Drivers]
Amazon Redshift (x64)=Installed

[Amazon Redshift (x64)]
Description=Amazon Redshift ODBC Driver (64-bit)
Driver=/opt/amazon/redshiftodbc/lib/64/libamazonredshiftodbc64.so
```

4. install `pyodbc` via `pip`

All these steps is better to implement as init script that could be attached to a cluster.

P.S. But do you really need to work through ODBC? Why not use more scalable [spark-redshift connector](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) provided by Databricks?

Comment: These instructions are for Linux; I'm using a Windows environment. Could you modify the instructions?

Comment: Are you talking about connecting from Azure Databricks environment, or from the local windows machine? If former, then it's a Linux

Comment: Azure databricks, but when I download the Debian file I can't look in the files. I would think we have to download the windows file to my windows desktop and then upload that to databricks.

Comment: Just put all shell commands like curl etc init shell script, upload it to dbfs and add as init script to a cluster

Comment: I'm not fully understanding. Do you mind spelling out exactly what I should put in a script to attach to the cluster?

Comment: main question - why do you need to use ODBC instead of `spark-redshift` connector? ODBC will run only on one node, not parallelized

Comment: We're using odbc for our other connections and want to keep it consistent.

Comment: it's not optimal for Spark... getting to your question - just put the `curl`, `apt-get`, etc. into the script. But you can debug all steps by doing things like `%sh curl ....` inside the Databricks notebook

Comment: what curl statement? Do you mind writing out exactly what I should put. Thanks